# Cal heatmap show nan value other color

Tags: javascript, cal-heatmap

Can cal heatmap.js let NaN value represent another color?

Now if my data has NaN, it will only be represented as 0.

```
 var cal = new CalHeatMap();

        cal.init({
            itemSelector: "#cal-heatmap",
            itemName: ["μm<br/>", "μm"],
            displayLegend: false,
            cellSize: 20,
            tooltip: true,
            data: data,
            start: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth() , new Date().getDate()-15),
            domain: "day",          // Group data by month
            subDomain: "hour",          // Split each month by days
            legend: [0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100],
            subDomainTextFormat: "%-H",
            legendCellSize: 15,
            browsing: true,
            nextSelector: "#domain-highlight-next-selector",
            previousSelector: "#domain-highlight-previous-selector",
            rowLimit: 12,
            range: 16,

        });
```